# Objective C - Empyt Elements

Tags: objective-c, xml, xsd

I wrote a program that produces an xml file; all works fine except that empty elements appear
as follows in the xml file

```
<key id="0"><key/>
```

instead of:

```
<key id="0"/>
```

This causes errors when the xml is accessed.

P.S. I have to follow the DTD stored here: `/System/Library/DTDs/KeyboardLayout.dtd`

This is how I create the NSXMLElements:

`NSXMLElement* space = [[NSXMLElement alloc] initWithName:@"key"];

[space addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"0"]]];`

So my question is, how is the code above to be modified i order to produce xml nodes as shown in the second example?

UPDATE:

Used the NSXMLCompactEmpyElement option as suggested and also used the NSXMLNodePrettyPrint option else all the nodes appear in one line.

```
NSData *xmlData = [mapping XMLDataWithOptions:NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement | NSXMLNodePrettyPrint];
[xmlData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly do you write it out?  In any case, the option you are looking for is `NSXMLNodeCompactEmptyElement`, which for instance is a valid option for `XMLStringWithOptions:` on a node.